# WeakReference on buttonClick

Tags: android

i have a problem with WeakReference. I get a error with this code...
Can you help me please?
I don't understand how use WeakReference with a button click event.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

 private final WeakReference<Context> contextReference;

 public MainActivity(Context context) {
     this.contextReference = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
 }
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 btnArrivi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Context context = this.contextReference.get();
  if(this.contextReference.get() != null) {

         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Arrivi.class);
         intent.putExtra("A_Compagnia", A_Compagnia);
         intent.putExtra("A_CodiceVolo", A_CodiceVolo);
         intent.putExtra("A_Citta", A_Citta);
         intent.putExtra("A_OraPrevista", A_OraPrevista);
         intent.putExtra("A_OraStimata", A_OraStimata);                
         intent.putExtra("thread",thread);

         context.startActivity(intent);
         }           
    }
```

Error:

```
contextReference cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

here:

```
     if(this.contextReference.get() != null) {
```

Comment: Did you forget the error code?

Comment: i have edited 1st post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, you need to implement the onClick metod of View.OnClickListener

Your second problem is that "this." in the inner anonymous class new View.OnClickListener() refers to the anonymous class, and not the MainActivity. This is a common error.

Use

```
MainActivity.this.contextReference
```

instead, or just simply

```
contextReference
```

since that is a fully qualified name in your code.

Actually, on the line above, you already do that, so just use context instead, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

 private final WeakReference<Context> contextReference;

 public MainActivity(Context context) {
     this.contextReference = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
 }

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     btnArrivi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = contextReference.get();
            if(context != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Arrivi.class);
                intent.putExtra("A_Compagnia", A_Compagnia);
                intent.putExtra("A_CodiceVolo", A_CodiceVolo);
                intent.putExtra("A_Citta", A_Citta);
                intent.putExtra("A_OraPrevista", A_OraPrevista);
                intent.putExtra("A_OraStimata", A_OraStimata);                
                intent.putExtra("thread",thread);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
         }           
    }
```